# Define int to be with 3 number ,az

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create model and in the model I want to define

field type int (num) that can get max 3 numbers (max 999),how can I do that?

I've read the following document but there is no place where I can define it on model class
that replicate DB

```
public class Model
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set{
    if(value  <1000) {
      num = value; 
    }else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: Im using MVc and after I create the model I create the DB context and from it the DB is generated ,how should I use it than?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Range] attribute to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx

Comment: Thanks voted up and iF I need it to string to be max 3 char like abc and not abcd ,how should I adopt this?

Comment: Use the [MaxLength] attribute. You should read-up on the other available data annotation attributes as well.

Comment: How can you please provide example?

Comment: Just read the documentation for it online. MSDN is a wealth of knowledge.